# Finding the x value after a matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following solution of a problem, and I was wondering about a hopefully quite simple thing in it:

[image]

I was wondering how do they get from [5,10,5] to 5x? I am pretty sure there is a simple explaination for that.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Notice what $A$ and $x$ are as defined in your first equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $5\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\2\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}5\\10\\5\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

I wanted to put this in the comments, but it wouldn't compile properly.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense, thank you.. I was sure it was just something I wasn't seeing right :)

Comment: It's fine to post as an answer, vadim: if questions are fully answered, but only in comments, they end up in the "unanswered" category... So, +1 for the fine answer.